# "for" loop and "if" condition for list creation in python

Tags: python, loops

```
source=[1,2,3,4,2,3,5,6]

dst=[]
for item in source:
    if item not in dst:
        dst.append(item)

print(dst) # [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Can I simplify code above something like this:

```
dst=[item for item in [1,2,3,4,2,3,5,6] if item not in 'this array']
```

Thanks

Comment: No, since you do not have a reference to "this" array in advance. Furthermore this uniqueness filter can be improved in case the items are hashable.

Comment: you can just use `set()` for it. you will get all unique items only

Comment: @Gahan: not per se, since a `set` can change the order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A set is probably what you are looking for, since you cannot refer to *this array* while it's being created:

```
>>> source = [1,2,3,4,2,3,5,6]
>>> set(source)
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

If you do want to keep original order, though, you can keep track of what you have already added to `dst` with a set (`seen`):

```
>>> source = [1,2,3,4,2,3,5,6]
>>> seen = set()
>>> dst = []
>>> for i in source:
>>>     if i not in seen:
>>>         dst.append(i)
>>>         seen.add(i)
>>>
>>> dst
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Not that sets are unordered and may loose your original ordering (actually the fact they _sometimes_ don't loose it is an implementation accident).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers good point. I've complemented the solution with an approach considering original order.

Comment: list(set(source)) - quickest way :)

Comment: PavelPerminov you don't guarantee original order with `list(set(source))`.

Answer (score 6):

No, list comprehensions cannot be self-referential.

You seem to want to remove duplicates from a list. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-whilst-preserving-order) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists) questions for a boatload of approaches to this problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can't reference `dst` from within the list comprehension, but you can check the current item against the previously iterated items in `source` by slicing it on each iteration:

```
source = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 5, 6]
dst = [item for i, item in enumerate(source)
       if item not in source[0:i]]

print(dst)  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

If using if and for is your requirement
How about this?

```
[dst.append(item) for item in source if item not in dst]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well instead of creating new list you can modify your existing list with list comprehension as shown below:

```
In [1]: source
Out[1]: [1, 9, 2, 5, 6, 6, 4, 1, 4, 11]

In [2]: [ source.pop(i) for i in range(len(source))[::-1] if source.count(source[i]) > 1 ]
Out[2]: [4, 1, 6]

In [3]: source
Out[3]: [1, 9, 2, 5, 6, 4, 11]
```

As another approach you can first get unique list with set and then sort it with reference to source index value as follow:

```
source = [1, 9, 2, 5, 6, 6, 4, 1, 4, 11]
d = list(set(source))
d.sort(key=source.index)
print(d)  # [1, 9, 2, 5, 6, 4, 11]
```